# rds db connection leak

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, rds

Would anyone show us how to debug or understand about the DB connections count in RDS instant of AWS. We are using Maria DB engine, RDS instant. Some period, DB connections count rocket sky high and our web (PHP apache back-end) falling over because of too many DB connections.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a connection pool to connect to the DB and not creating a new connection for every request.

I know little about PHP, but a quick google search led to the below link on how to implement pooling with PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.pooling.php